# iPhone 5s reset password—wrong date of birth

Tags: apple-id, password, activation-lock

I was having problems with my daughter’s iPhone 5s touch screen. I was advised to do a factory reset, as this could rectify the problem. After I did this I encountered Activation Lock.

You’ve guessed it, she can’t remember her Apple ID password. We tried to reset it, since she can’t remember her email password either, we can’t login to her email. We then opted for the security questions, but it’s rejecting her date of birth.

What options do we have?

Comment: I inferred from context (Activation Lock) that by “hard reset” you meant a factory restore (`Erase All Contents and Settings`). Feel free to clarify if I’m mistaken. People mean lots of different things when they say, “hard reset,” so I find it best to avoid that phrase.

Comment: Yes, i mean factory restore.

Answer (score 1):

Head on over to https://iforgot.apple.com/ and see if you can get your situation sorted out—although I’m not sure you’ll get any more options than what you already went through.

If that fails, you’ll need to contact Apple directly and be prepared to prove that the iPhone is indeed yours/your daughter’s.